# Remove middle play/pause botton from Vimeo video

Tags: jquery-plugins, vimeo, vimeo-player

I need to autoplay a Vimeo video inside my site. I removed the toolbar and all buttons from the video through my Vimeo Plus account but I can't figure out how to remove the middle Play/Pause button.

[image]

There is no setting for that on Vimeo and I can't find any hack to remove it because it is embedded inside an iframe with a different domain from my site.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/138579264" width="500"
height="275" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So I want to know if there are some jquery player that can play a Vimeo video (https://vimeo.com/138579264) without that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the play button from our player, but since are a PRO member you can use a third-party player if you’d like: https://vimeo.com/s/adg.

Comment: Thanks but how [vooplayer](http://www.vooplayer.com) can remove all controls from a Vimeo video just putting a Vimeo video URL there, even using a video URL from a Vimeo Basic account? How is it possible?